# Creating arbitrary sized groups from a list of object with lambda/linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, chunking

Is there a way with the pre-existing Linq functions to create arbitrarily sized groups from a list of item?

For instance:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

When doing something like list.Group(3) would produce an IEnumberable of IEnumerables that look like the sequence below.

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've got this in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) as [`Batch`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs).

```
var batch = source.Batch(3);
```

As you can see from the code, it's not really trivial to implement efficiently with the "standard" LINQ operators, but it's clearly doable. Note that it involves buffering the input, as the resulting sequences need to be independent.

If you *do* want to do it with just the standard operators, a less efficient implementation would be:

```
// Assume "size" is the batch size
var query = source.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                  .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / size, pair => pair.value);
```

EDIT: Just to show why this is safer than John Fisher's answer, here's a short but complete program to show the difference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] source = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

        var skeet = SkeetAnswer(source, 3);
        var fisher = FisherAnswer(source, 3);

        Console.WriteLine("Size of the first element of Skeet's solution:");
        Console.WriteLine(skeet.First().Count());
        Console.WriteLine(skeet.First().Count());
        Console.WriteLine(skeet.First().Count());

        Console.WriteLine("Size of the first element of Fisher's solution:");
        Console.WriteLine(fisher.First().Count());
        Console.WriteLine(fisher.First().Count());
        Console.WriteLine(fisher.First().Count());
    }

    static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> SkeetAnswer(IEnumerable<int> source,
                                                     int size)
    {
        return source.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                     .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / size, pair => pair.value);
    }

    static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> FisherAnswer(IEnumerable<int> source,
                                                      int size)
    {
        int index = 0;
        return source.GroupBy(x => (index++ / size));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Size of the first element of Skeet's solution:
3
3
3
Size of the first element of Fisher's solution:
3
2
1
```

While you *could* call `ToList()` at the end, at that point you've lost the efficiency gains of the approach - basically John's approach avoids creating an instance of an anonymous type for each member. This could be mitigated by using a value type equivalent of `Tuple<,>`, so that no more *objects* would be created, just pairs of values wrapped in another value. There's still be the slight increase in time required to do the projection then grouping.

This is a good demonstration of why having side-effects in your LINQ queries (in this case the modification to the captured variable `index`) is a bad idea.

Another alternative would be to write an implementation of `GroupBy` which provides the `index` of each element for the key projection. That's what's so nice about LINQ - there are so many options!

Comment: Wow,very good idea, if last of code add .Select(p=>p.ToList()).ToList() is better result view.

Comment: @RedHat: I wondered about that, but it depends on what you need to do with the groups.

Comment: It's nice to see the comparison and the "safety" issue pointed out.  Note also that with JonSkeet's answer, you do pay a price of using more memory (one *new { value, index }* per source item) and more time spent running the query.

Comment: @JohnFisher: Yup, that's certainly true. As I say, I prefer reliability over performance - and if you *really* want performance, use the MoreLINQ implementation instead :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Was that a shameless plug? :P

Comment: @JohnFisher: I guess so, although it makes no real difference to me whether people use MoreLINQ :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any built in methods to do this, but it's not too difficult to implement.  The group method you are referring to does something more like a SQL group.  What you are talking about is often called chunking.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
//var items = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int index = 0;
var grouped = items.GroupBy(x => (index++ / 3));
```

There is no need to bother with the extra select steps from other answers. It wastes memory and time just to create throwaway objects with an extra index value.

**Edit**:

As Jon Skeet mentioned, iterating over *grouped* twice could cause problems (when the *items* being grouped don't divide cleanly into the group size, which is 3 in this example)).

To mitigate that, you could use what he suggests, or you could call *ToList()* on the results.  (Technically, you could also reset the index to zero each time you iterate over the group, but that's a nasty code smell.)

Comment: Better hope you don't iterate over `grouped` twice... it won't do what you expect in that case. Putting side effects into lambda expressions is generally a bad idea - I'd rather take a *reliable* approach which is slightly inefficient than a flaky approach any day.

Comment: This code is just as reliable as your suggestion.  They each have side effects, and there are so many ways to run into problems iterating over linq queries multiple times that most people should be aware of ways to handle that issue already.

Comment: Nope, untrue. There's no side-effect in my query, because the `Select` method will start the index again each time you iterate over the results. Try iterating over my query twice, and it'll give you the same results both times. Iterate over your query twice with the sample data and the second time you'll end up with { 1, 2 } then { 3, 4, 5 } because `index` will have the value `7` to start with. I can edit my answer to prove this if you want...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Your side effect isn't variable changes, but performance and memory usage changes.

Comment: Performance and memory usage doesn't normally count as a side-effect in this sort of thing - certainly not when talking about *correctness* which is what I *obviously* meant. Claiming that your code is "just as reliable" as mine is simply untrue, IMO, as it's so easy to use incorrectly.

Comment: @JonSkeet: If someone is iterating over a very large set of items, memory and performance certainly come into play.  You can't ignore the size of the source when describing side effects for a general solution.  However, I wasn't suggesting that he place this code into a library, but that it will do the job where he needs it.  Clearly, the question's intent was not to write a library, because the asker doesn't even want to include a non-default library to achieve his goal.

Comment: If they're iterating over a very large set of items, you need to bear in mind that the anonymous types will become garbage immediately - it's not like the *long term* memory usage grows. I'd *still* use my solution over yours, until it was proven to be too inefficient - at which point I'd use a more custom implementation anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's very reasonable.  I only truly cared that people understand the differences.  Which they choose really doesn't matter to me -- even if it's MoreLINQ. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor this code to a extention method and use it for List:

```
int i = 0;
var result = list
    .Select(p => new { Counter = i++, Item = p })
    .Select(p => new { Group = p.Counter / 3, Item = p.Item })
    .GroupBy(p => p.Group)
    .Select(p=>p.Select(q=>q.Item))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You don't need that 'non-functional' increment code, use the other form of Select: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx